# Executable Jar built by maven can't find logback.xml

Tags: java, maven, logback

I have built my project using maven. And I have a executable jar. But my executable jar can not find `logback.xml`. What should I do?
It's important to me not to put `logback.xml` in my jar file because I want to edit it without making the project again.

Comment: How do you reference logback.xml? How do you expect it to be found outside the jar?

Comment: You'll need to include it in the runtime classpath then. Of course you could just edit it from inside the jar (jar files are zip files).

Comment: i know my problem but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: How do you run your app?

Comment: java -Dlogback.configurationFile = logback.xml -jar App.jar

Answer (score 1):

You should specify full path to the config file:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config/logback.xml App.jar
```

Source: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html